# Help demonstrate how to arrive at the implication of some given inequalities and equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Given:

1. $0<x<y<1$
2. $z=x+y$
3. $x=u$
4. $y=z-u$
5. $0<u<z-u<1$

I need to show that this implies:

1. If $0<z<1$, then $0<u<\frac{z}{2}$, and
2. If $1<z<2$, then $z-1<u<\frac{z}{2}$.

I can observe that $0<z<2$ but I am not able to make any progress on getting the 2 required implications. Please show me the steps as well as the reasoning to solve these kind of questions in general. I am especially perplexed at splitting the $z$ from $0$ to $1$ and $1$ to $2$

This is part of a larger question but I've only included only the parts that I think are needed to deduce the implication. So let me know if more assumptions are needed in order to get the implications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are really asking two questions, namely how to solve your specific inequalities and also how to go about proving inequalities in general, I will consider them separately and in that order.

---

### Question 1

**Deductions:** Using your given information, there are a few observations that we can make that will be helpful later in the proofs of your inequalities (of course, I made these deductions while trying to prove the inequalities--I did not see how they related to your problem until I needed them).

$\underline{\text{Observation 1}}$:
Notice that 
\begin{align}
z-1 &= x+y-1\tag{$z=x+y$}\\[0.5em]
    &= u+y-1\tag{$x=u$}\\[0.5em]
    &< u.\tag{$y<1$; thus, $y-1<0$}
\end{align}
Since we are also given that $u<1$, we effectively have that 
$$
z-1<u<1.\tag{$\dagger$}
$$

$\underline{\text{Observation 2}}$: Notice that
$$
\frac{z}{2} = \frac{x+y}{2} = \frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{2}<1;\qquad\text{(since $x<1$ and $y<1$)}
$$
also,
$$
\frac{z}{2}=\frac{u+y}{2}=\frac{u}{2}+\frac{y}{2}>\frac{u}{2}+\frac{u}{2}=u.
$$
Since $\frac{z}{2}<1$ and $\frac{z}{2}>u$, we effectively have that
$$
u < \frac{z}{2} < 1.\tag{$\dagger\dagger$}
$$
**Givens:** Using your initial givens and the observations $\dagger$ and $\dagger\dagger$ we just established, let's list out all of the givens we currently have to work with.
\begin{align}{}
0<x<y<1\tag{1}\\[0.5em]
z=x+y\tag{2}\\[0.5em]
x=u\tag{3}\\[0.5em]
y=z-u\tag{4}\\[0.5em]
0<u<z-u<1\tag{5}\\[0.5em]
z-1<u<1\tag{6}\\[0.5em]
u<\frac{z}{2}<1\tag{7}
\end{align}
Now proving your inequalities will actually be fairly straightforward.

**Inequality 1 ($0<z<1\to 0<u<\frac{z}{2}$):** Start with the left-hand side and work towards the right-hand side using the information you are given (the approach will be the same for the second inequality):
\begin{align}
0<z<1 &\to 0<x+y<1\tag{since $z=x+y$}\\[0.5em]
      &\to 0<2x<x+y<1\tag{since $x<y$ and $x>0$}\\[0.5em]
      &\to 0<2u<z<1\tag{since $x=u$ and $z=x+y$}\\[0.5em]
      &\to 0<u<\frac{z}{2}<\frac{1}{2}\tag{divide throughout by $2$}\\[0.5em]
      &\to 0<u<\frac{z}{2}.\tag{desired expression}
\end{align}
Thus, we see that $0<z<1\to 0<u<\frac{z}{2}$, concluding the proof of the first inequality.

**Inequality 2 ($1<z<2\to z-1<u<\frac{z}{2}$):** Starting with the left-hand side,
\begin{align}
1<z<2 &\to 0<z-1<1\tag{subtract $1$ throughout}\\[0.5em]
      &\to 0<z-1<u<1\tag{since $z-1<u<1$}\\[0.5em]
      &\to 0<z-1<u<\frac{z}{2}<1\tag{since $u<\frac{z}{2}<1$}\\[0.5em]
      &\to z-1<u<\frac{z}{2}\tag{desired expression}
\end{align}
we reach the right-hand side. Thus, we see that $1<z<2\to z-1<u<\frac{z}{2}$, concluding the proof of the second inequality.

### Question 2

In regards to proving inequalities in general, you need to realize it truly is an *art form*, and, as with most forms of art, it takes time and practice to get better. Numerous [books](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=inequalities) have been written just on inequalities and how to strategically attack them. There is such a great range of difficulty when it comes to proving inequalities. Here is a sample of inequalities that differ greatly in difficulty (links are to answers I have provided to such inequality problems on MSE):

1. [Easy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1119826/prove-and-disprove-the-following-inequality/1119883#1119883)
2. [Average](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111287/prove-a-b-c-if-and-only-if-b-c-a-b-c/1111310#1111310)
3. [Hard](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1114615/if-0ab-prove-that-a-sqrtab-fracab2b/1114633#1114633)
4. [Very hard](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691807/proofs-of-am-gm-inequality/1107594#1107594)

The more problems you encounter and solve, the better and better you will get at solving them. I will conclude my answer with an example.

---

**Example:** Compare $6^{1/4}$ and $4^{1/3}$ without using a calculator. Is one greater than the other?

*Answer.* Observe that
$$
6^{\frac{1}{4}}=6^{\frac{3}{12}}=(6^3)^{\frac{1}{12}}=216^{\frac{1}{12}}
$$
and
$$
4^{\frac{1}{3}}=4^{\frac{4}{12}}=(4^4)^{\frac{1}{12}}=256^{\frac{1}{12}}.
$$
Since $256$ and $216$ are both being raised to the same power, and $256>216$, we can clearly see that $4^{1/3} > 6^{1/4}$ since
$$
4^{\frac{1}{3}} = 256^{\frac{1}{12}} > 216^{\frac{1}{12}} = 6^{\frac{1}{4}}.
$$

---

Knowing that it helps to make such manipulations comes with time and practice. Notice that it would otherwise be quite difficult to compare the values in the example as $4^{1/3}\approx 1.5874$ and $6^{1/4}\approx 1.5651$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I just have small point to ask for clarification. From the 5 given information only, is it possible to realize that $z$ has different inequalities between $0<z<1$ and $1<z<2$? In other words, from $1$, I can see that $z$ can take on values between $0$ and $2$ but I have no clue why I would want to split that into the $2$ inequalities above. My study guide immediately deduced the implications without any hints on the need to consider the values of $z$ in the two inequalities.

Comment: @mauna I cannot make a very informed judgement without having your book present to look at for myself, but it should be fairly simple to realize that there are different inequalities involving $z$ when the conditions change. The *kind* of inequalities you get will often change when you change your parameters. Hopefully that will help.

Comment: @mauna Post what as a separate question?

Comment: I meant I'll post the question I asked in my first comment as a separate question (This time I'll post the question in my book in its entirety)

Answer (score 1):

From 4., $0<u<z-u$. In particular, $$0<u\tag{$\spadesuit$}$$ and $u<z-u$. The latter can be rewritten as $2u<z$, or $$u<\frac z2.\tag{$\heartsuit$}$$ Hence, it follows from ($\spadesuit$) and ($\heartsuit$) that $0<u<z/2$, as desired.

---

Now 4. implies also that $ u<z-u<1$. In particular, $u<z-u$ or $2u<z$, or $$u<\frac z2\tag{$\clubsuit$}$$ as before. On the other hand, $z-u<1$, or $$z-1<u.\tag{$\diamondsuit$}$$ Putting ($\clubsuit$) and ($\diamondsuit$) together yields $z-1<u<z/2$, as desired.

---

Note that neither inequality hinges on whether $0<z<1$ or $1<z<2$. It's only that the inequality $0<u$ gives a stronger (and more useful) lower bound on $u$ than the inequality $z-1<u$ whenever $z<1$. Analogously, $z-1<u$ gives a stronger lower bound on $u$ than $0<u$ whenever $z>1$.