# Which is bigger $\frac{1}{{\sqrt{1001}}+ {\sqrt{1000}}}$ or $\frac {1}{10}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the best way to find the inequality? I know the answer but my solution is messy.

Comment: $\sqrt{1001} + \sqrt{1000} > 10 + 10 > 10$.

Comment: @WilliamStagner Reverse?

Comment: Haha, yes. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the hint in the comments. Since
\begin{align}
\sqrt{1001} + \sqrt{1000} &>\sqrt{1000}+\sqrt{1000}\\
&=10\sqrt{10}+10\sqrt{10}\\
&=20\sqrt{10}\\
&>20
\end{align}
We have that
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1001}+\sqrt{1000}}<\frac{1}{20}<\frac{1}{10}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very straightforward way of seeing the relation without doing any fancy manipulation:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1001}+\sqrt{1000}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{100}+\sqrt{100}}=\frac{1}{20}<\frac{1}{10}.
$$

Comment: in fact, this inequality is so strong that I wonder if the original question was not in fact $\sqrt{101}+\sqrt{100}$.... 0.016 vs. 0.1

Comment: @MichaelChirico I think you are probably right; otherwise, this inequality seems to be quite easy to establish.

Comment: and, as your answer proves--quite easy to establish anyway (relatively speaking...)

Comment: @MichaelChirico Precisely. You may like the answer I provided for [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128877/help-demonstrate-how-to-arrive-at-the-implication-of-some-given-inequalities-and). Skip to the very bottom of my answer where I consider which one is bigger: $6^{1/4}$ or $4^{1/3}$. That's a pretty fun one! Much more interesting than the problem by OP.

Answer (score 1):

With something like this it could help to start with approximation:
$$
\sqrt{1000}\approx \sqrt{1001} \approx 30.
$$

So your fraction is about $\frac{1}{60}$, which is plenty less than $\frac{1}{10}$.

---

Just saw that you already knew the direction, so here's how I'd formalize:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1000}+\sqrt{1001}}< \frac{1}{\sqrt{900}+\sqrt{900}}=\frac{1}{60}<\frac{1}{10}.
$$

Answer (score -3):

For the time being, leave the relation $@$ undefined.
$\frac1{10}@\frac1{\sqrt{1001}+\sqrt{1000}}$
$\sqrt{1001}+\sqrt{1000}@10$
Compute $\sqrt{1001}$ and $\sqrt{1000}$.
Call their sum $x$.
$x@10$
Should $@$ be $\lt$, $=$ or $\gt$?